# Typescript dynamic parameters and return type

Tags: typescript

I'm developing an Angular application that has to communicate with a backend that has some security restrictions that I have to deal with on every call. To facilitate the work with these calls, I've created a wrapper method like this:

```js
type ApiResponse<T = any> = {
  status: number,
  data: T,
  error?: string
}

type ApiCall<T=any> = (...args: any[]) => ApiResponse<T>;

const makeApiCall = <T extends ApiCall>(apiCall: T, ...params: Parameters<T>): ReturnType<T> => {
  // Execute the "apiCall" method with the parameters, deal with restrictions, parse the response etc
}
```

So, let's say I have 2 API calls (they can have any number of parameters and types):

```
const f1: ApiCall<string> = (a: number, b: string) => {
  // Do logic
  return {
    status: 200,
    data: "Data sample"
  }
}

const f2: ApiCall<string[]> = (a: string, b: string, c: number, d: number) => {
  // Do logic
  return {
    status: 200,
    data: [ a, b ]
  }
}
```

I can use the wrapper to run them:

```
makeApiCall(f1, 2, 4);

makeApiCall(f2, "String", "Another", 10, 20);
```

However, nothing prevents me from sending wrong parameters number or type, like:

```
makeApiCall(f1, 2, 4, "WRONG PARAMETER");

makeApiCall(f2, "Wrong number and type of params", 10, true);
```

Would it be possible to have type safety with the above definitios so the Typescript compiler showed hints and errors when using the wrapper?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to avoid declaring explicit generic parameters. TS should infer all types. Let him do the hard work :)

```js
type ApiResponse<T> = {
    status: number,
    data: T,
    error?: string
}

type Fn = (...args: any[]) => any

const makeApiCall = <
    F extends Fn
>(apiCall: F, ...params: Parameters<F>): ReturnType<F> =>
    apiCall(...params)

const f1 = (a: number, b: string) => {
    // Do logic
    return {
        status: 200,
        data: [a, b]
    }
}

const f2 = (a: string, b: string, c: number, d: number) => {
    // Do logic
    return {
        status: 200,
        data: [a, b]
    }
}

/**
 * Ok
 */
// Return -> {  status: number;  data: (string|number)[];  }
const result1 = makeApiCall(f1, 42, 'str');

// Return -> {  status: number;  data: string[];  }
const result2 = makeApiCall(f2, "String", "Another", 10, 20);


/**
 * Errors
 */
makeApiCall(f1, 2, 4); // expected error


makeApiCall(f1, 2, 4, "WRONG PARAMETER"); // expected error

makeApiCall(f2, "Wrong number and type of params", 10, true); // expected error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAgmCWAlCBnMB7AdiiAeAKgHxQC8UA3gLABQUdUKwAhsAK4oBcUmrAtgEYQATgBoa9KABMWTLvjG16woeiEB%20LoyHxMAcxoBfGjVCQoAMUykoACgB0DpkN2coTTCADaAXQCUpYncQY2oAYyxGKF4mAGsIOHgAYSYAGxTrXHF6cygIAA9gCExJFAtMGkIbJgRktK5zESgHOzAnJl5XAAU23ghCoRRcc0JfLmQ2IUx8cDxhgKy6aqTUlPsHVqF2lF8Q8OxgKAAzAEZrKq4eAWFG-k1gbT1-EmIqRToAeneoABF0KBT0Lp4KEFlAhH1WJMKKCJIwWOwuAAmAAMyIUEgk0mYXE8TBu3lBRmoRJoe0ih0RZ1kDHuOl0NzuD3pUFCFz4glEUjZVyETxeoM%20Pz%20AKBILeYIhUNeGPocLYrhRaJh9Cx1Nx%20MJhhC7wAVDrxDqoAB5GIG940QXjSFWAC0LzocoR3HZwgA3HRVVwbFo6QAfS4c3w%20d1QIlkg7glCsFLAU5kaJxBK1VYnRoAFkRjQA5Fos75XdqvlaoXaKA7mPLuRyQ56aUzg3QwxEI6ho8BKfHYvEaisbBTGgAiADKtL0A8HMEw6GAAAthOOoMc0VAUfmQha9QaoABRIQqAZmmgJ7vLNJ946NTNQNP5qCC-KQUKFSS5PeqdfUY9J3uplfpwcAOqIEaAByADiUCdDAiAwAAstu%20DbogA63veeSPs%20r77iEX49me-ZQAOAEqHozo8m4xRQKY0DoIcUAbFsC5Lo09ysBAqFfA%20EBPhAL7KKoQA)